# macro for colouring track changes

Tags: macros, trackchanges

I am revising an article and have to put in colour the changes.
I do this manually (I created a macro) but it is tedious and imply another work when the article will be accepted (if it is^^).

```
\definecolor{green(munsell)}{rgb}{0.0, 0.66, 0.47}
\newcommand{\revONE}[1]{{\color{green(munsell)}#1}}
```

Is there a way to define a macro which will automatically colour the added text (using track changes) in the output file?

ps: I am totally new to latex...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check out [latexdiff](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexdiff), which can highlight changes between different revisions of the latex source file.

I used it to highlight changes in a manuscript as requested by the reviewers and it work quite well for that purpose. In my case it had some kinks with changes in tables (if I recall correctly), but nothing that couldn't be easily fixed (manually) with the help of the package's [issue tracker](https://github.com/ftilmann/latexdiff/issues).

Comment: Thanks! I struggled a bit to install it on my mac but now it is almost perfect. I just still struggle to do not have long  citation in the margins (I tried to used \begin{sloppypar}....\end{sloppypar} but it does not work... and i do not find anything on the forum...)

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem you're having. Could you paste a picture or some code that illustrates it?

Comment: Yes sure, the problem is detailed here, with a picture : [link](https://latexdiffcite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ )

Comment: Good to know, thanks :)
I never noticed this issue, most likely because I used `style=numeric`, which doesn't lead to these long diffs when modifying citations.